# error: element number 2 undefined in return list. I'm new to this, pls help me

Tags: octave

```
x = fopen('pm10_data.txt');
fseek(x, 8,0);
dat = fscanf (x,'%f',[2,1000]);
dat = transpose(dat);
a = dat(:,1);
b = dat(:,2);
[r,p] = cor_test (a,b)
fclose(x);
r
p
```

this is what i got,

```
r =
```

scalar structure containing the fields:

```
method = Pearson's product moment correlation
params =  76
stat =  6.2156
dist = t
pval =    2.5292e-08
alternative = !=
```

***Run error***
error: element number 2 undefined in return list
error: called from
**tester**.octave at line 7 column 6

Comment: it says the function `cor_test` returns only one output, but you requested two. check the definition of that function, i.e. check the file `cor_test.m`

Comment: Please read the descriptions of [tag:matlab] and [tag:octave]. The languages are not the same, so only use both tags if you're explicitly asking about the differences or similarities between the two

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you're referring to the `cor_test` function from the statistics package, even though you don't show loading this in your workspace.

According to the documentation of `cor_test`:

```
 The output is a structure with the following elements:

 PVAL          The p-value of the test.
 STAT          The value of the test statistic.
 DIST          The distribution of the test statistic.
 PARAMS        The parameters of the null distribution of the test statistic.
 ALTERNATIVE   The alternative hypothesis.
 METHOD        The method used for testing.

 If no output argument is given, the p-value is displayed.
```

This seems to be what you're getting too.

If you want the p value explicitly from that structure, you can access that as `r.pval`

---

The syntax `[a, b, ...] = functionname( args, ... )` expects the function to return more than one argument, and capture all the returned arguments into the named variables (i.e. a, b, etc).

In this case, `cor_test` only returns a single argument, even though that argument is a struct (which means it has fields you can access).

The error you're getting effectively means you requested a second output argument `p`, but the function you're using does not return a second output argument. It only returns that struct you already captured in `r`.